# А зачем два сайта: rus.SE и russian.SE?

Tags: обсуждение

Один приехал из Сети Знаний, другой был тут изначально.

Будут ли они объединены? Или будет как с MathOverflow и math.SE?

Comment: can someone explain how this site came about?  and how come, the same as with the russian stack overflow, it has existed before being created?!

Comment: @cnst, There was existing Q&A site about Russian language not in StackExchange network. Now it got intergrated into the StackExchange. Just like http://ru.stackoverflow.com .

Answer (score 10):

Объединения не будет.

Будет больше похоже на [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) и [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Один из них для носителей языка, а другой для людей, изучающих язык.

Так и здесь - [Russian Language](http://russian.stackexchange.com) для учащихся, [Русский язык](http://rus.stackexchange.com) для уже русскоговорящих.

Comment: Тогда "Russian Language" нужно переименовать в "RLL - Russian Language Lerning".

Comment: Ссылка на комплементарный вопрос: http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/376/now-there-two-sites-rus-se-and-russian-se-shall-the-scope-of-this-site-be-chang

Comment: @_Vi Вполне возможно. Команда, ответственная за управление сайтами, рассмотрит этот вопрос.

Comment: Неособенно понятно, почему вы хотите переименовать уже созданный сайт с уже существующими вопросами и т.д.?  Все рускоговорящие что, на неправильном сайте вопросы задавали?

Comment: @cnst Это вопрос мне или _Vi? Мы (Stack Exchange) стараемся не переименовать сайты. Все пользователи задавали вопросы на правильном сайте... просто раньше был сайт о русском языке в Сети Знаний, и теперь он в нашей сети, несмотря на то, что у нас уже был сайт о русском для не-русскоговорящих.

Comment: @AnnaLear, а разве ваш сайт о русском был действительно для не-русскоговорящих? Можно ли ссылочку на эту Сеть Знаний, что это такое.

Comment: @cnst Извиняюсь, под русскоговорящими я подразумевала носителей языка. Наш сайт был в основном для, например, американцев, изучающих или преподающих русский язык. Сети Знаний больше не существует. Два сайта оттуда перешли к нам - Stack Overflow на русском и Русский язык.

Comment: Кто же всё-таки основал и владел Сетью Знаний, и почему эта сеть больше не существует?

Comment: @AnnaLear, ну вот я специально отыскал.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language.  "Russian Language
Beta Q&A site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Russian language."  То есть, мне до сих пор не понятно, почему сайт теперь постфактум переименован для нерусских.

Comment: @cnst Никто его не переименовал. Если им пользуются русские, это тоже хорошо. Пусть нерусских учат, как правильно. :) Посмотрите на English Language Learners и English Language & Usage. Разница между ними *по тематике* примерно такая же, как и здесь.

Comment: finally found the link -- http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/2993/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9 -- is it some kind of a secret?

Comment: @cnst Not at all. I just don't know much about it (forgot that meta.hashcode.ru was still up, for one thing) and don't have the links handy.

Comment: @AnnaLear, so, you launch this major community, and there's not even any sort of blog entry about it, or a press release from your side?  or a public thank you note to the original founders and maintainers of those communities?  are they getting a cut from your advertising on these two new sites that originated from them?

Comment: ok, i guess he works at SE now: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky http://careers.stackoverflow.com/chabanovsky ; it's interesting to note that hashcode.ru was all written in golang. :)

Comment: @cnst We aren't running any advertising on these sites. One of the original founders, Nicholas Chabanovsky, is the community manager in charge of them. Not sure about press releases and such... I think we have a blog post in the works? I'm just a developer. (I believe hashcode.ru was written in Python. ;))

Comment: @AnnaLear, no, they use go -- http://siliconrus.com/2013/06/startap-set-znaniy-rossiyskiy-stack-exchange-na-samookupaemosti-i-bez-investorov/ ; blog post in the words -- hasn't the conversion happened a few months ago already?!