# Что это за сайт?

Tags: обсуждение

Возможно, я что-то пропустил. Но откуда взялся этот сайт SE? Был http://russian.stackexchange.com, который был предложен в Area 51, запущен, развивается. А недавно наткнулся на этот, успешно существующий но — откуда?!

Я видел вопрос «[Зачем два сайта](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/%D0%90-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-rus-se-%D0%B8-russian-se)», но, во-первых, я не знаю, что такое Сеть Знаний, упоминаемая в нём. А во вторых, мне кажется, ответ на этот вопрос хорошо бы лёг и в «Справку».

И, кстати, не знаю, нельзя ли как-то изменить URL-ы. А то http://russian.stackexchange.com и http://rus.stackexchange.com, ведущие на совсем разные сайты выглядят как-то непонятно.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Я видел тот вопрос, но он спрашивает «зачем», а я спрашиваю «откуда». Т.е. тот _вопрос_ может являться _ответом_ на этот (если предположить, что все знают, что такое Сеть Знаний, а я этого быстро выяснить не смог). И ещё я спросил про URL. Но я дополнил свой вопрос. Ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Насколько я понял, этот сайт был перенесен с ныне не существующего проекта hashcode.ru (сеть знаний), который использовал движок stackexchange. Видимо организаторы хэшкода больше не могли поддерживать свой проект и попросились сюда. Ну, а перенос данных уже был делом техники. Кстати некоторые ссылки на хэшкод (например [такая](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/14699)) и сейчас успешно редиректятся сюда.

Comment: @Artemix: Спасибо, это то, что я хотел увидеть. К сожалению, администратор(ы) не внял(и) просьбе открыть вопрос, поэтому не могу принять этот ответ. Придётся ограничиться голосованием за комментарий.

Comment: Кстати stackoverflow на русском тоже скорее всего оттуда переехал. Вот, например, есть такие [результаты поиска hashcode.ru](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hashcode.ru).

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто руки не дошли на прошлой неделе. Вопрос заново открыт, и я перевела ответ от @Artemix в секцию ответов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял, этот сайт был перенесен с ныне не существующего проекта hashcode.ru (сеть знаний), который использовал движок stackexchange. Видимо организаторы хэшкода больше не могли поддерживать свой проект и попросились сюда. Ну, а перенос данных уже был делом техники. Кстати некоторые ссылки на хэшкод (например [такая](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/14699)) и сейчас успешно редиректятся сюда.

Comment: Хэшкод сейчас существует в несколько ином качестве. Сюда полностью или частично перенесены три "раздела": русский, математика и программирование. Несколько других остались под эгидой "сети знаний" - хэшкода. Но там сейчас пыль стряхивать некому, так что в каком-то смысле можно сказать и "ныне не существующий". Проект вполне себе поддерживался, Сюда попросились не от беспомощности, а скорее как выгодная самопродажа.   Во всяком случае там было обставлено.

Comment: Математику, похоже, не переносили - с трудом удалось зайти на http://math.hashcode.ru/ (сам hashcode.ru перенаправляет на ru.stackoverflow.com). Даже не понятно как другие форумы искать если главная страница перебрасывает на другой сайт.

Comment: А собирались... Остальные - через сеть знаний. Сейчас ссылку найду. Давно там не был.

Comment: Да... Признаю, моя инфа немного устарела. Хэшкод / "Сеть знаний" ныне состоит из одной математики. Остальное снесли. Мои старые ссылки не работают. Возможно и математику в скором времени перенесут, как и собирались.

Comment: @behemothus, математику изначально не планировали переносить, так как там очень высокий процент вопросов составляют решения домашних заданий.

Comment: И что? Разве это как-то мешает? да там и сейчас такие разговоры ведутся. Я видел разговоры про домашние задания на математике в связи с переездом, но это не расматривалось как препятствие, просто как факт.

Comment: @behemothus, Видимо мешает, если Николай Чабановский ещё в первых сообщениях о переходе писал, - "На платформу Stack Exchange мигрируют два из трех сообществ: ХэшКод и Русский язык. Сообщество Математика продолжит развиваться независимо. Это связано с направленностью вопросов на форуме. В сообществе задается большое количество вопросов - домашних заданий, в то время как на ХэшКоде и Русском языке данный тип вопросов является неприемлемым".  [Источник](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/2992/сеть-знаний-детали-перехода-на-платформу-stack-exchange)

Comment: Да? Я это не так интерпретировал. Ну ладно, проехали.